# How does a pair unify with the types of the Arrow functions

Tags: haskell, arrows

Some of the functions for working with Arrows are quite handy to use on pairs.  But I can't understand how the types of these functions unify with a pair.  In general, I find the types of the Arrow related functions to be quite confusing.

For example, we have `first :: a b c -> a (b, d) (c, d)`, which means little to me.  But it can be used to, say, increment the first number in a pair:

```
Prelude Control.Arrow> :t first (+1)
first (+1) :: (Num b) => (b, d) -> (b, d)
```

And

```
Prelude Control.Arrow> :t (&&&)
(&&&) :: (Arrow a) => a b c -> a b c' -> a b (c, c')

Prelude Control.Arrow> :t (pred &&& succ)
(pred &&& succ) :: (Enum b) => b -> (b, b)
```

Could someone please explain how this works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an instance for `Arrow (->)`.  So

```
(&&&) :: (Arrow a) => a b c -> a b c' -> a b (c,c')
```

has the instantiation

```
(&&&) :: (->) b c -> (->) b c' -> (->) b (c,c')
```

or, written in more conventional notation,

```
(&&&) :: (b -> c) -> (b -> c') -> (b -> (c,c'))
```

The rest should follow from that.

I use the arrow functions (especially `(***)` and `(&&&)`) *all the time* on the `(->)` instance.  My usage of those combinators for any other instance of `Arrow` is very rare.  So whenever you see `a b c`, think "(generalized) function from `b` to `c`", which works for regular functions too.

Answer (score 2):

The first arrow takes a normal arrow, and changes it to perform its operation on the first element in a tuple and outputs the result as an arrow

```
a b c -> a (b, d) (c, d)

a b c -- is the input arrow, an operation that maps type b to c
a (b, d) (c, d) -- is the output arrow, an operation that maps a tuple (b, d) to (c, d)
```

it uses d as a dummy for the unknown second type in the tuple

&&& takes two arrows that take the same input and creates an arrow that takes that input, duplicates it into a tuple and runs one of the arrows on each part of the tuple, returning the altered tuple.

for some solid tutorial, check out:
http://www.vex.net/~trebla/haskell/hxt-arrow/lesson-0.xhtml

Answer (score 1):

I did this blog post not long ago about how to use Arrow functions on pure functions

http://blog.romanandreg.com/post/2755301358/on-how-haskells-are-just-might-just-be-function

I try to cover all the basic Arrow methods in a really simple and detailed fashion.

Cheers.